# Как остановить скрытие блока при mouseover/out?

Tags: javascript

Помогите доработать задумку.
На странице есть кнопка или ссылка с ID, при наведении на которую рядом с ней появляется блок в котором я создаю dom элементы.
Проблема в том что у меня не получается сделать так чтобы после появления блока и переводе мышки в блок, он оставался видимым.

Вот пример того что сейчас имеется https://jsfiddle.net/gh8thfxb/

```
(function(){
    var hoverDropdownBoxs = [];
    var hoverDropdownBox = function( o, options ){

    this.parentDOM = document.querySelector('body'); // parent object
    this.triggerDOM = o; // Hover triger object (such as button) for Hover mode
    this.options = options;
    this.dom = null;
    this.items = [];
    this.footerItem = null;
    this.id = hoverDropdownBoxs.length;

    this.init();
    hoverDropdownBoxs.push(this);
    this.appendToParent();

  };

  hoverDropdownBox.prototype.init = function( opt_container ) {

    var container;
    if( ! opt_container) {

        container = document.createElement('div');
      container.className = 'hover_dropdown_box hover_dropdown_box_hover hover_dropdown_box_hide';
      container.dataset.hoverDropdownBoxId = this.id;
      this.dom = container;
      this.parentDOM.appendChild(container);

    } else {
        container = opt_container;
      this.dom = container;
    }

    container.style.width = this.options.width + 'px';
    container.style.height = this.options.height + 'px';
    container.style.display = 'none';

  };

  hoverDropdownBox.prototype.appendToParent = function( ){

        var options = this.options;

        this.triggerDOM[this.id].dataset.hoverDropdownBoxId = this.id;
    this.triggerDOM[this.id].addEventListener('mouseover', this.hover.bind(null, this, this.triggerDOM[this.id]));
    this.triggerDOM[this.id].addEventListener('mouseout', this.unhover.bind(null, this, this.triggerDOM[this.id]));

    };

  hoverDropdownBox.prototype.hover = function(o, h, e) {
    var id = h.dataset.hoverDropdownBoxId;
    var dom = hoverDropdownBoxs[id].dom;
    var parentDOM = hoverDropdownBoxs[id].parentDOM;
    var triggerDOM = hoverDropdownBoxs[id].triggerDOM;

    dom.style.top = '50px';
    dom.style.display = 'block';
    dom.classList.remove('hover_dropdown_box_hide');
  };

  hoverDropdownBox.prototype.unhover = function(o, h, e) {

    var id = h.dataset.hoverDropdownBoxId;
    var dom = hoverDropdownBoxs[id].dom;
    dom.classList.add('hover_dropdown_box_hide');
    dom.style.display = 'none';

    };


  appendHoverDropdownBox = function(e){
        var o = document.querySelectorAll('#' + e.id), s = new hoverDropdownBox( o, e );
    };

})();




appendHoverDropdownBox({
    id: 'navi',
  top: 40,
  width: 200,
  items: {}
});
```

Как сделать так чтобы при наведении на желтый блок мышкой, он не исчезал?

Comment: Добавьте setTimeout для скрытия желтого блока, а при наведении на него очищайте таймаут через clearTimeout()

Comment: во-первых ты элемент вставляешь неправильно, скорее не туда, он у тя после тега script, а должен быть перед. вставляй не просто appendChild(), а так  куда.insertBefore(что, перед-чем). конечно я не могу знать твоих мыслей, но если ты при загрузке страницы сразу создаешь элемент и вставляешь body , на кой мучить браузер? опиши его просто в body и скрой, а при наведении что-бы он появлялся, создай отдельной функцией появление и отдельно исчезновение, и как сказал Cheg выше, setTimeout. И еще, вопрос, просто любопытно, я тоже новичок JS, на кой использовать  тег <a> и запускать функцию из href?

Comment: Cheg, подскажи что не так, если увести курсор с блока, то он не исчезает теперь =) А если с самой кнопки уводить курсор, то все в порядке.  Вот код https://jsfiddle.net/webphp/vz6uLmue/